# NextJS upload to S3 using AWS SDK v3 and new NextJS app router

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js

I'm trying to figure out how to upload to S3 via NextJS.  I'd like to use the presignedURL method if possible. And I'd like to use the newer v3 AWS SDK as the older one gives deprecation warnings about how its going to be in maintenance mode soon.

Every tutorial I find on this is either outdated via the AWS SDK, or is out dated because NextJS has a new app router that works different than before.  Each tutorial seems to use different npm packages that I suppose the author preferred but it makes them difficult to piecemeal together.

After piecing together what works from several different tutorials online. I was able to get a presignedURL using the v2 SDK only.

Can anyone show me a bare bones example of using NextJS 13.4 app router api that uploads to AWS S3 via aws sdk v3, or point me to a place that has a working example? Even Vercel's own documents are outdated compared to their latest release.

Comment: Have a look at this blog post - https://www.mtechzilla.com/blogs/how-to-upload-images-and-videos-to-amazon-s3-with-next-js-and-aws-sdk-v3

Comment: I tried this one. I tried it again just now to see why it didn't work.  Immediately you get:

```'"@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner"' has no exported member named 'createRequestPresigner'```

and also this uses the old route handlers.

Also if you google for "createRequestPresigner" it exists no where on line other than in this article. So i'm not sure if this article ever worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issues today and finally got it working. I ended up needing the `@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner` package to generate pre-signed URLs. I found the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner) on that pretty helpful. Take a look at the code below for reference.

**Relevant Dependencies**

I'm using Next.js 13 App Router and AWS SDK v3.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.12",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.388.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.388.0"
  }
}
```

**Client Uploader Component**

Simple uploader component. I plan on refactoring this into a multistep process, but it works fine for the purposes of demonstration.

```
"use client"

// React
import { useState } from "react"

// Services
import { uploadMedia } from "@/services/frontendServices"

const MediaUploader = () => {
  const [uploadedUrl, setUploadedUrl] = useState("")

  const handleChange = async (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const file = e.target.files?.[0]!
    const res = await uploadMedia(file)
    console.log(res.status)
    setUploadedUrl(res.uploadedUrl)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Upload Media</h2>
      {uploadedUrl && <img src={uploadedUrl} alt="Preview" />}
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={handleChange}
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default MediaUploader
```

**Client Service Function**

The `uploadMedia` service function takes in a media file as an argument. It makes a `POST` request to the backend and gets back the necessary pre-signed URLs. The `putUrl` is used to upload the actual media file to the bucket. Finally, it returns the status of the upload and a `getUrl` for previewing the image.

```
export const uploadMedia = async (file: File) => {
  try {
    // POST request to backend route handler
    const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/media`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ fileName: file.name, fileType: file.type, fileSize: file.size })
    })
    
    // Response includes a putUrl for upload and a getUrl for displaying a preview
    const { putUrl, getUrl } = await res.json()

    // Request made to putUrl, media file included in body
    const uploadResponse = await fetch(putUrl, {
      body: file,
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": file.type }
    })

    return { status: uploadResponse.ok, uploadedUrl: getUrl }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

**Route Handler**

The route handler creates a new photo entry, and responds with the `putUrl` (for uploading the file) and a `getUrl` (for previewing the file). The route handler is located in `src/app/api/media/route.ts`.

```
// Relevant imports
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner"
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"


// Initialize S3Client instance
const client = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
})

const POST = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  try {
    const user = await currentUser()
    if (!user) return new Response('Unauthorized', { status: 401 })

    const { fileName, fileType, fileSize } = await req.json()
    if (!fileType || !fileName || !fileSize) {
      throw new Error("There was a problem with the file!")
    }

    // Create a new media entry in database.
    // The uploaded media file will be stored in the S3 bucket 
    // with a name (Key) matching the id (PK) of the newMedia/photo. 
    const newMedia: Photo = await prisma.photo.create({
      data: {
        fileSize: fileSize,
        fileName: fileName,
        mimeType: fileType,
        authorId: user.id,
        authorName: `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`
      }
    })

    if (!newMedia) { throw new Error("Something went wrong!") }

    // PutObjectCommand: used to generate a pre-signed URL for uploading
    const putCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
      Key: newMedia.id,
      ContentType: fileType,
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    })
    // Generate pre-signed URL for PUT request
    const putUrl = await getSignedUrl(client, putCommand, { expiresIn: 600 })

    // GetObjectCommand: used to generate a pre-signed URL for viewing.
    const getCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
      Key: newMedia.id,
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_NAME,
    })
    // Generate pre-signed URL for GET request
    const getUrl = await getSignedUrl(client, getCommand, { expiresIn: 600 })

    return NextResponse.json({ putUrl, getUrl }, { status: 200 })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw error
  }
}

export {
  POST,
}
```

Comment: This is a wonderfully thorough answer. Thanks!